# Exposing a private type with auto: where can it be useful?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13532784/771663)  it was discussed why exposing a private type with `auto`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {

  class PrivateClass {    
  public: 
    void bar() { cout << "PrivateClass" << endl; }
  };

public:

  PrivateClass foo() {
    PrivateClass a;
    return a;
  }

};

int main() {

  Base b;
  auto p = b.foo();
  p.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

is perfectly fine by the C++11 standard. What I still don't get is how this idiom may be useful in a real application.
**Are there problems where this idiom can be effectively used, or it should be considered as a "curious" side-effect of the keyword?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be useful if the return type is unspecified.  For example, the returned object from a call to `std::bind`, or formerly `boost::bind`, is not specified.  It is some implementation-defined functor, but you can't actually know its type without looking at implementation details.  Before C++11's `auto` keyword, you could use `boost::function` as a variable type for storing the result of `bind`, or you could pass the result of `bind` to a function which takes a template argument.  With C++11, you can store the result object using `auto`.

So, if a class has some internal type, it is not necessary to expose the actual type to a public API.  A user of the class can simply use the `auto` keyword, and the API documentation can say the type is "unspecified".  This keeps the actual internal type a private implementation detail, which can often improve encapsulation.

Comment: I don't think that this really answers the question. It's a good answer to a different question, which is "what is the use of `auto`?"

Comment: I think it answers the question. The internal type name can be kept private while allowing the client to work with objects of that type.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I'm not sure why you think this doesn't answer the question.  He wants to know why someone would use `auto` to store a private type returned from a function.  The answer is because this way the private type can be unspecified in the public API.

Comment: The answer did not say that when I wrote my comment. I really wish this FGIW would _stop_.

Comment: This question can aswell be "Exposing a private type with type deduction?" and be retagged to C++ (without -11 suffix). And this accepted answer applies just as-well to that question (passing the result to a function template).

Answer (score 1):

Wheter the "auto" keyword & subclasing provides such feature, the concept of "private types" seems unpractical.

Before O.O.P., some developers hide some type using a (void*) pointer, to a "struct". Another more updated cases allowed an object of a given class, been exposed only by a superclass.