# "auto" type deduction compiles while explicit type gives error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, auto

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and I've found something that is kind of weird. I'm not writing something that I necessarily require to be compatible across multiple compilers, but it may become later(when the code is put on web, users don't want to get compiler errors), but I don't want to write something that is wrong, or just not native.

So this is test code:

```
class A{
    class B{
        public:
        int i;
    };
    B myB;
public:
    B& getB() { return myB; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A::B& b = a.getB();
    auto& b2 = a.getB();
}
```

The first line inside main pops `error C2248: 'A::B' : cannot access private class declared in class 'A'` whereas the second line compiles normally. I wonder, is auto supposed to work like this or is this another bug in Visual Studio?

I don't have any other compiler I can test it on with

You can even write stuff like `std::cout << b2.i << "\n";` and it compiles perfectly fine

As per  πάντα ῥεῖ's comment, I tried ideone with gcc 4.8.1 and it compiles in the same way, first line is error, second line is perfectly fine.

Comment: _`PS: I dont have any other compiler I can test it on with`_: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/online-c-compilers especially http://rise4fun.com/vcpp

Comment: Interesting. I had never considered the legality of something like this, but it seems to compile with gcc and clang also.

Comment: With the code in `main` to initialize `b` and `b2`, the output statement leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `b` and `b2` are references to objects that have been destructed

Comment: well, I wrote that in haste, so I just used temporary, but good point, I will edit the question with that one line. Also to add, this doesnt require reference or pointer to compile, you can return instance as well

Comment: seems it is actually. But I didnt find it when I searched. Nah lets not lie, I didnt search

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe my list [here of online compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652386/1708801) is more up to date ... correction or updates are welcome.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'd say that your link there exactly points to the same place I've linked in my comment?!? Or did you mean [this one](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) in particular? Looks promising ...

Comment: There's nothing unusual here. The types of lambda expressions and bind expressions are equally "unknowable", but you can still use them in deduced contexts. `auto` is just one more way of performing deduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's supposed to work like that. Access applies to names, not the entities they refer to.

Even without `auto` it has always been legal to e.g. pass the result of `getB` to a function expecting a `B`.

Comment: Also, if you create a public `typedef` of a private class, using the `typedef`'d name throws no error while using the private class name does.

Comment: Or a typedef :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: re "Access applies to names, not the entities they refer to", *sort of*. For example, C+11 §12.1/1 "Constructors do not have names". Arguably destructors don't have names either, and indeed in C++11 there is at least one (non-normative) note that argues that way.

Comment: but considering e.g. the duplicate's answers, such fine points may not necessarily matter on SO.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is supposed to work like that, yes, and yes that means that it can expose private types.