# Private nested classes - C++11 compiler misbehavior? Or as designed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, private-members

Consider the following code:

```
class Main
{
  private:
      class Inner
      {
        public:
          void DoSomething() {}
      };

  public:
    static Inner* CreateInner() { return new Inner(); }
 };
```

It is impossible to compile the following:

```
Main::Inner* pInner = Main::CreateInner();
pInner->DoSomething();
```

Because we'll get a compiler error 'C2248: cannot access private class decalred in class Main'

However, using the following syntax **will compile** and execute smoothly:

```
auto pInner = Main::CreateInner();
pInner->DoSomething();
```

Suddenly, (to my surprise, anyway...), the inner private class is 'visible' to the outside world...

Does anyone aware to this compiler behavior?
Is it considered 'valid' to use the auto keyword according to the C++11 standard in this case, or is it some kind of a bug?

It behaves as described on both:

1. Visual Studio 2010 - platform toolset v100

   Visual Studio 2013 - platform toolset v120

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I would be quite surprised if you got the second case to compile in VS2010 as [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) was introduced in C++11 which is (mostly sorta) supported starting as of VS2013.

Comment: Confirmed behaviour with gcc 5.2 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db691f65c9c806d0

Comment: I confirmed this behaviour with C++14 compiler. Here is code link, https://ideone.com/ef7HMO (call to DoSomething() is successful)

Comment: This link explains a few things about this behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: It does compile in Visual Studio 2010, because, although it is prior to C++11, VS2010 included the 'auto' keyword along with other C++0x features (as it was called prior to C++11) .
See here: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/04/01/The-Evolution-of-Visual-C-in-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx