# Public function taking private class as parameter

Tags: c++, class, types, private, access-control

Assuming I have this code:

```
class MyClass {
private:    
    class NestedPrivClass {};
public:
     MyClass(NestedPrivClass){}
};
```

Is there a way for another class to create an instance of `MyClass` by calling the public constructor?

Shouldn't using private nested class as parameters in public functions be a compilation error? (As it is impossible to call them.)

Comment: it is not impossible to call it, you just have to get a `NestedPrivClass` by other means

Comment: What are you trying to do? You could use it like this, for instance: `static MyClass* MyClass::Create() { return new MyClass( NestedPrivClass() ); }
`

Comment: See ["Why can I use auto on a private type?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this should not be an error.  Just because the name is private does not mean it is an invalid type.  For instance if we added a public static function that returns a `NestedPrivClass` like

```
class MyClass {
private:    
    class NestedPrivClass {};
public:
     MyClass(NestedPrivClass){}
     static NestedPrivClass getNestedPrivClass() { return NestedPrivClass{}; }
};
```

We could then construct a object of `MyClass` like

```
int main()
{
    auto private_name = MyClass::getNestedPrivClass();
    MyClass foo{private_name};
}
```

Comment: Is that me or is that `auto` circumventing access restriction? Using `MyClass.NestedPrivClass` explicitly where `auto` is used would cause a compilation error, right?

Comment: @Arkadiy See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type.  This is the expected behavior.