# Using auto to instance private classes

Tags: c++11, private, auto

Consider the following code:

```
struct A{
private:
    struct B{};
public:
    B make() const{return B{};}
};

int main(){
    A a; 
    auto b1 = a.make(); (void)b1;
//  A::B b2 = a.make(); (void)b2; // compile error: B is a private class
}
```

**What is the logic behind being able to compile `b1` line while the second `b2` line?** After all `auto` is supposed equivalent to replace the name of the class.

If it is what I think, this shows that `auto` is not simply syntax sugar.
`auto` on private classes can be used *force* the user not know about certain types but still be able to use instance of them! (and this was not possible in C++98?)

**Am I mistaken in this interpretation?**

Comment: You are right in your assessment of the situation. I have seen a question on SO regarding that. The main point is that the name `A::B` is `private` but not the type, if that makes sense. I'll try to find the duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: @RSahu, thanks. I find interesting that this was no possible in C++98.

Comment: @alfC, in C++98, it was possible to access the type in the sense that you  could use the `public` member functions/variables of the returned object without assigning it to a variable. Somethink like `a.make().b_func()`.