# Declaring a struct within class, defining in source file

Tags: c++

How is it correctly done? It needs to be declared bforehand in order to use it as a return value of a certain function within a class. Is it even possible?

For example:

```
class foo 
{
  struct in_foo;
public:
  in_foo * func();
};
```

Comment: Please specify what actual issues do you experience with the code above (or some other code, in which case please provide it as well).

Comment: If you want to access `in_foo` outside of `foo` you should put the struct declaration after public.

Comment: The provided code seems correct (except probably that `in_foo` should be `public` if one wants to use it after it called `foo()`). Please describe what problem your experiencing.

Comment: You can surely forward declare `in_foo` the way you did and define it in your cpp file. You might want to move it in public. But in general, this seems weird, because the user typically should know the definition of `in_foo` in order to use the return value.

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov Yeah, sorry. It's for internal use - it is actually a private method. I have no idea why i wrote it here as public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Here's an example:

```
class foo 
{
  struct in_foo;
public:
  in_foo * func();
};

struct foo::in_foo {
};

foo::in_foo* foo::func()
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    foo f;
    auto p = f.func(); // ok
    // the following would be an error:
   // foo::in_foo* p2 = f.func();
}
```

Note that, as shown above, you can only declare variables of `foo:in_foo` by using `auto` (as `foo:in_foo` is private).

Comment: I was just wondering why `auto` is allowed. Doesn't this violate the privateness of `in_foo`? Edit: found [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type)

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov yeah, this can be a bit unintuitive.

Comment: If you declare a member inside ```in_foo```, say a ```int x```, can you access to it via ```p->x```? (Assuming, e.g., that ```foo::func()``` returns a pointer to an existing ```in_foo``` object)

Comment: @francesco Yes, you can.

Comment: @francesco Here is [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61eff9ada4c1d99e)

Comment: Thanks! I find it quite unintuitive. I understand that using ```auto``` you do not violate privateness of ```foo::in_foo``` because you do not *reveal* ```foo::in_foo```, but then I am nonetheless allowed to access its members.

Comment: Oh.. Now I see where the error is coming from.. I got `struct foo * in_foo;` I though it will declare a struct foo, and a variable in_foo, but I have to write it in a separate lines. Otherwise I get `no tag member named in_foo` error

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what the question is, but the answer is probably "yes you can"...

**foo.h** file:

```
class foo 
{
public:
  struct in_foo;
  in_foo * func();
};
```

**foo.cpp** file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"foo.h"

struct foo::in_foo
{
    int i;
};

foo::in_foo* foo::func()
{
    foo::in_foo* res = new foo::in_foo();
    res->i = 23;
    return res;
}

int main()
{
  foo::in_foo* temp = foo().func();
  std::cout << temp->i;
  delete temp;
}
```

This code will output `23`.

Note that `struct in_foo;` must be after the `public` statement, else, main can't declare `foo::in_foo* temp`