# Access to class' nested private class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Normally, it is not possible to access a nested class if it is declared in `private` section from outer scope:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Outer
{
    private:
        class Inner
        {
            public:
                void sing() const { std::cout << "la la la\n"; }
                void laugh() const { std::cout << "ha ha ha\n"; }
        };

    private:
        std::vector<Inner> inners;

    public:
        void add() { inners.push_back(Inner()); }
};

int main()
{
    auto o = Outer();
    auto i = Outer::Inner();  // error: 'class Outer::Inner' is private within this context
}
```

[Example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aNvNdWA67OK2L12K)

**However, with a small trick, the access is granted**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Outer
{
    private:
        class Inner
        {
            public:
                void sing() const { std::cout << "la la la\n"; }
                void laugh() const { std::cout << "ha ha ha\n"; }
        };

    private:
        std::vector<Inner> inners;

    public:
        Inner & add() { inners.push_back(Inner()); return inners.back(); }
};

int main()
{
    auto o = Outer();
    auto i = o.add();
    i.sing();
    i.laugh();
}
```

[Example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kl7hzfq7DVOhztpB)

Is the above valid C++ (11, 14, 17, etc.) or are just G++ (10.0.0) and Clang (10.0.0) playing tricks on me?

If this is valid, which rule allows this access?

Naively, I would assume that I cannot hold on to what `Outer::add()` returns, or at best can hold it, but not access its members.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: cppreference includes it on their explanation of nested classes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types